# Any way to suspend/resume WildFly docker container?

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, resume, suspend

WildFly 9 added the suspend/resume ability which I want to use on a Wildfly container. The container started as a deamon and Eclipse deploys to a mapped folder. But how can I use the functions above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you do suspend or resume in a normal machine?

Comment: @Rao I don't know. The normal machine is just running and I can redeploy my changes via maven. I'm not very familiar with WildFly, so it's a question in general